# HOw to make simple search with laravel

Tags: laravel, search-form

i try to create forms search in laravel.. 
when the title of the **title** article is searched .. then the title will appear.. i am search **title** article form Article Table

this is my **HomeController**

```
...
  public function search(Request $request){
      $cari = $request->get('search');
      $Title = Article::where('title', 'LIKE', '%' .$cari . '%')->paginate(10);
      return view('/article/show', $cari);
    }
```

this is my **header.blade.php**

```
**...
<div class = "col-md-4">
      {!! Form::open(['method'=>'GET', 'url'=>'/article/show', 'role'=>'search']) !!}
      <div class= "input-group custom-search-form">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="search" placeholder="Judul..">
        <span class="input-group-btn">
          <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn-btn-default" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i>Cari</button>
          </span>
        </span>
        {!! Form::close()!! }
      </div>
    </div>
```

thi is my route..

```
..
Route::get('/article/show', 'HomeController@search');
```

.
But when i am typing on search form.. i am getting error like this

```
(2/2) QueryException
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'show AND is_show = TRUE and `articles`.`deleted_at` is null' at line 1 (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `articles` where category_id=show AND is_show = TRUE and `articles`.`deleted_at` is null)
```

.

please tell me which part is wrong
Thanks...

Comment: where category_id=show

Comment: what query is returned?

Answer (score 0):

You're sending a POST request as GET. Switch the GET to POST, or include the searched term in the URL and remove the Request $request part of your search(Request $request) function since GET will not provide an instance of Request. Just make it search($terms) instead if you go that route. I would personally just switch to POST though.

IE:

```
Route::post('/article/show', 'HomeController@search');

{!! Form::open(['method'=>'POST', 'url'=>'/arti...
```

Comment: (1/1) MethodNotAllowedHttpException.. i can try to swith get to post and get the error

Comment: You can get Request with a GET

Answer (score 0):

In your form add

```
{{ csrf_token() }}
```

Also you will want to check if 'search' has a value, so wrap it around a `if ($request->search)`

Also, it looks like you may have a SQL error somewhere else on the page which is cause this.

Comment: around your code in function. Although, its not needed. Just additional validation.

Comment: This error is not related to this. Its somewhere else

Comment: according to you based on my code above .. what is wrong??..
 i have relational tables.. table article with table categories is relation..

Comment: I don't know I don't see your code. Also, you're returning in your function what the user entered. Not even the result of the SQL data.

Answer (score 0):

check your table name, or try this

```
      public function search(Request $request)
      {
         $cari = $request->get('search');
         $data['result']= DB::table('articles')->WHERE('title', 'LIKE', '%' .$cari . '%')->paginate(10);
         return view('/article/show', $data);
      }
```

your form

```
       <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" method="GET" action="{{url('search')}}">
        <div class="input-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" name="search">
            <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">
              <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
            </button>
        </div>
      </form>
```

Comment: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'show AND is_show = TRUE and `articles`.`deleted_at` is null' at line 1 (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `articles` where category_id=show AND is_show = TRUE and `articles`.`deleted_at` is null)

Comment: your db using sqlserver ? my sugestion is use mysql, because you will get much trouble if your project using framework and your db is sqlserver. better using mysql,its much easier

Comment: where the deleted_at come from ? is that one of your name column in articles table ?